# PHP SQL Code Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I am learning the object oriented  PHP. Now I have the mission to get a connection. I'd like to show my code and ask you for some optimization support. Maybe there are several absolutely wrong understood things. I don't hope so. I want to improve my design. In real the Constants of course have the rights values. BIG THANKS! :)

// index.php

```
<?php
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/config.php' );
new db(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

// config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'host');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');

if (!defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

require_once(ABSPATH . '/includes/classes/db.class.php');
?>
```

// db.class.php

```
<?php
class db
{
    protected $db_host;
    protected $db_user;
    protected $db_password;
    protected $db_name;

    function __construct($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName)
    {
        global $mysqli;

        $this -> db_host       = $dbHost;
        $this -> db_user       = $dbUser;
        $this -> db_password   = $dbPassword;
        $this -> db_name       = $dbName;

        $this -> mysqli = new mysqli($this -> db_host, $this -> db_user, $this -> db_password, $this -> db_name);
        $mysqli = $this -> mysqli;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should not use globals in a method it totally destroys the encapsulation

Comment: This is something for Code Review....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no concrete question and belongs on the code review site.

Comment: @Eiko please vote to close as "Too Broad" or "Unclear" if there is no actual programming question/problem. That being said, if the code works correctly it would be on-topic on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tips I found some time back, On the DB layer

Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once

```
static $connection;
```

Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet, Create connection only once

```
if(!isset($connection)) {
     // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
    $config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini'); 
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
}
```

If connection was not successful, handle the error

```
if($connection === false) {
    // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
    return mysqli_connect_error(); 
}
```

Finally return connection

```
return $connection;
```

More info: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a good basic understanding. As far as the config and hard coding of database credentials there are better practices for security that you can learn.

You can create a '.conf.ini' file and store it out of the web directory containing the following. Doing this can stop the hard coded database credentials from being displayed within the web root directory and the '.' prefixing the 'conf' if I'm not mistaken will ensure its processed first. The following is both acceptable as a php file as well as an .ini file.

```
;<?php
;die();

;/*
[General_Database_Settings]
SERVER_ADDRESS = server
DATABASE_NAME = database_name
TABLE = table_name
DATABASE_USERNAME = db_username
DATABASE_PASSWORD = db_password

;*/
;?>
```

This will allow you to parse the settings in using:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('/.conf.ini');
```

You can then access the variable in the config file easily:

```
$server_address = $config['SERVER_ADDRESS'];
$database_name = $config['DATABASE_NAME'];
$username = $config['DATABASE_USERNAME'];
$password = $config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'];
```

Using this in combination with PDO (PHP Data Objects) found here [PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) will give you a great boost in understanding object oriented programming in php as well as establishing secure database connections.

I was doing the same thing and reading this helped me learn everything faster with better production practices. (For example preventing SQL injection using prepared statements.)

Comment: Thank you for the Link and your practices. I will study them :)